# Many Navigation Components are Ok?

Tags: android, navigation

I have problem with navigation component. I would like to know whether my idea is correct.

I have `main_activity`, `A_activity`, `B_activity`. `Main` is parent for `A` and `B`.

Each activity (`A`, `B`) should have own `NavHostFragment` (`A` and `B` have many fragments like list, detail etc.)

Example flow: `main` -> `A` -> `listA` -> `detailA`.

The back button works ok.

Questions:

How can I implement navigate up (toolbar arrow) in fragments and `A` activity?

Is it possible to go back from first fragment `listA` to main?

Is using many navigation component the correct solution (every `A`,`B`... activity)?

In my first fragment I don't have navigate up options. How enable this?

Activity code:

```
private void setUp() {
    setSupportActionBar(mActivityTrainingBinding.toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_container);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_container).navigateUp();
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_container).navigateUp();
}
```

Manifest code:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.training.TrainingActivity" />
```

Navigation code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_training"
    app:startDestination="@+id/trainingListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/trainingListFragment"
        android:name="pl.apps.ui.training.list.TrainingListFragment"
        android:label="TrainingListFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_trainingListFragment_to_trainingDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/trainingDetailFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/trainingDetailFragment"
        android:name="pl.apps.ui.training.detail.TrainingDetailFragment"
        android:label="TrainingDetailFragment" >
        <argument
            android:name="trainingId"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Can anyone comment my code? I cannot navigate up from first fragment in activity.
It it start point of my nav graph. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your thinking is correct. Each activity has its own navigation graph and host fragment.

> How implement navigate up (toolbar arrow) in fragments and A activity?

In a standard way - using `setupActionBarWithNavController` and override `onSupportNavigateUp()` in Activitiy. No code in fragments is required.

> Is it possible to back from first fragment listA to main?

Yes, again, it's a standard behavior. If listA is first fragment (top level), then after pressing back you will be switched to previous activity.